# How can I use composition for a more complex code reuse case?

Tags: reactjs

React [recommends](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) composition over inheritance

Given the follow structure

```
<A>
 <B>
  <C/>
 </B>
</A>
```

which I can render by this:

```
function Base()
{
  return <A><B><C/></B></A>;
}
```

I want to override  by more specialized classes, but I need `<C />` to be still be embeded as an inner child by the Base class.

I know if I didn't want to include `<C/>`, I could just do:

```
function Base({children})
{
  return <A>{children}</A>
}
```

and override with:

```
function Sub()
{
  return <Base><span>some complex html</span></Base>
}
```

But I want the base class to still embed  inside the children element.

Now if I was using inheritance, I would do something like this:

```
class Base
{
 inner()
 {
   return </C>;
 }

 middle()
 {
   return <B>{inner()}</B>;
 }

 outer()
 {
   return <A>{middle()}</A>;
 }

 render()
 {
    return outer();
 }    
}
```

and just appropriately override `middle` in a Sub class.

**What are good ways I can achieve the same thing using composition?**

I've thought about including a replacement element:

```
function Sub()
{
  return <Base><span>some complex html<span id='replace'/> </span></Base>
}
```

And then getting the Base class to modify it's children prop, by looking for the replacement element, but that's not elegant solution.

Another option would be to extract `<C/>` from the Base, and just use it in Sub, but the `< C/>` functionality is strongly related to `<A />` and so would be better left encapsulated in the same component.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a callback rather than children

```
function Base({ onMiddle = () => {} })
{
  return <A>{ onMiddle(< C/>) }</A>
}
```

Then the more specialized components, can just call the callback, which is passed the inner content.

```
function Sub()
{  
    return <Base onMiddle=(inner) => { <span>complex html{inner}</span>} />
}
```